# Как передать из формы IP адрес в сокет Objective C \ С ?

Tags: сокеты, objective-c, ui, c, формы

Есть код, который устанавливает соединение по заданному адресу на заданный порт, шлет и получает от него сообщение.

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons([self.portField.stringValue intValue]); // или любой другой порт...
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

В addr.sin_port передаю номер порта из формы. Так же из формы я хочу передавать адрес в addr.sin_addr.s_addr.

Я пытался сделать двумя двумя способами

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([self.portField.stringValue cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

и

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([self.portField.stringValue UTF8String]);
```

Но ни один из этих способов на работает. Подскажите, как правильно передать строку в параметр?

**Обновление**

Действительно, проблема была со строками. Помогло следующее решение:

```
addr.sin_port = htons([ports integerValue]); // или любой другой порт...
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adr]UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, дело в том что надо брать не self.portField.stringValue, а self.portField.text

А вообще можно было воспользоваться оберткой на obj-c https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

**Обновление**

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket - тут есть пример. На словах могу сказать что я точно его использовал для ловли мультикаст-пакетов и все было хорошо если не считать того что айпадовская сетевуха вырубается через 5 минут, но при работе напрямую то же.

Кстати, когда мы думали что проблема с мультикастом из-за реализации написали свою версию сокета и там мы использовали `sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([group UTF8String]);`, где group это `NSString` а порт у нас был объявлен как `NSInteger`, так что в целом вроде как у вас. Может, не в этом дело?

Comment: Так ведь нет self.portField.text. Я не под iOS пишу, а под OSX.

Comment: так вы это нигде не указали )

Comment: Нет ли у Вас примера кода с использованием данной обертки?))

Comment: увы, нет. Я использовал его только на iOS

Comment: Ну хотя бы для IOS, разницы особо нет.

Comment: @aknew, а у Вас github не заблокирован?

Comment: Обновил ответ. @avp , работает и дома, и на работе. Вчера не работал из дома, с работы работал

Comment: А у меня дома заблокировали... 

Пишут

    Доступ ограничен  по решению суда или по иным основаниям, установленным законодательством Российской Федерации.

Comment: @avp, попробуйте указать в настройках dns 8.8.8.8. Обычно это помогает))

Решение вопроса нашел, написал в первом посте.

Comment: @maxprig , есть подозрение что вместо [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", adr] можно дернуть [adr description], именно он и вызывается вроде при всяческих WithFormat:@"%@" , минус один вызов метода и минус одна переменная в куче это всегда хорошо, особенно для obj-c, который далеко не самый быстрый язык